# Three 3D positions in a straight line, but the middle one doesn't have Z. How to find it?

Tags: geometry

A=(x,y,z) -> B=(x,y,?) -> C=(x,y,z) I have 'em all except the one in between, B-z. I need it in a formula.
Here's an example that explains it better:

[image]

I'm doing this for 3D collision on a slope in a Doom-like engine: A 2D object on a 2D polygon, with extra 3D coordinates on each vertex. So far I've discovered the 3D position ahead and behind the object as its moving/looking at the polygon edges, narrowing it down to a straight line. I'm thinking I could measure the distance between point-ahead and point-behind, as 100% of point-ahead's Z, and point-ahead and object-position as X% of point-ahead Z, plus point-behind's Z? Maybe there's another way entirely to do this

PS I hope I'm asking this correctly without breaking any rules, thanks for reading!

Comment: Use the two points you have to define the line. Then set $x=y=0$ on your line to get the $z$ coordinate of $(0,0,z)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to understand, how do I define the line? I'm not using graphs, and technically I only have the positions

Comment: Two points define a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following equalities must hold (if the line is not parallel to one of the coordinate axes):
$$
{x_A-x_B\over x_B-x_C}={y_A-y_B\over y_B-y_C}={z_A-z_B\over z_B-z_C}.
$$
Note that the first equality turns out to be false, if the data in your picture are to be taken seriously.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! My friend helped me make that into this:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/770126649412681729/1051579545398030426/image.png
I do believe it's correct! However for my solution it's working only like 50% of the time... time to bug-test!